# Common Custom STS for both Active and Passive Federation with ACS

Tags: wcf-security, wif, acs

I've a Custom IP-STS(non-ADFS) for passive federation scenario. For an active client I've created custom IP-STS for active federation referring to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446531.aspx . However, I'd like to use a single IP-STS for both passive and active clients. How do we handle this with a common FederationMetadata.xml since the entityIds(endpoints) should be different for active and passive scenarios?  And what are the changes we need to make in order to use a single STS for both?

Passive federation endpoint:
"https://localhost/MyCustomIdp" - Clients will be redirected to Login page.

Active federation endpoint:
"https://localhost/MyCustomIdp/Service.svc" - Clients will pass credentials to this service. The service has a ws2007HttpBinding endpoint and returns SAML token for given credentials after validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the ADFS metadata - you'll see both passive and active endpoints.

In terms of how to implement it, have a look at [Thinktecture IdentityServer](http://thinktecture.github.com/).